# Autossh dies after time

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel

My setup is

- Ubuntu 10.04 on AWS
- Autossh to create a tunnel for MySQL

The tunnel is automatically created using Upstart (/etc/init/autossh.conf):

```
respawn
console none

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on [!12345]

script

#user/IP Address redacted
exec autossh -M 20000 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 xxxx@x.x.x.x 

end script
```

On boot the tunnel is created, works great. After some random idle time it dies. Any thoughts on how to keep it alive? I don't know what's killing autossh.

Comment: I guess it's time to turn up debugging.  http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/README

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec autossh -f -M 20000 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -NL 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 ubuntu@50.18.153.24
```

I discovered I needed -N to allow -f on autossh to work. With -f, it now drops to the background. Turns out the root user was killing autossh.

Why, I'm not sure but now that it runs more like true daemon this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is a timeout setting in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on the server. The randomness is probably related to times when the mysql server isn't sending data for `$idle_timeout_value`

You should be able to check your logs on the server to see what is causing the disconnect.

Comment: Thanks for the rely Zypher. Isn't autossh supposed to restart the tunnel when the connection idles and dies?